# c# - Show MessageBox if any Checkbox in a DataGridColumn/Row is unchecked

Tags: c#

I have a program in `C# WPF` where in the program I have three different `columns`. Let's call these columns A, B and C. Now I would like my program to display a `MessageBox` with a warning if **ANY** of the `Checkbox` in column B is unchecked, provided column A and C is checked.

I managed to get the warning `MessageBox` if I am ticking at the CURRENT row for those 3 columns. For example, A is checked, B is unchecked and C is checked, therefore a `MessageBox` should pop out when I clicked submit.

Let's say I started with row A with column A checked, B unchecked and C checked. Then I proceed with  row B and set all columns to checked and hit submit, it should  pop out a `MessageBox` claiming row A has an unchecked box in B column. So far, I couldn't figure out how to make this work.

Here is a snapshot of the checkbox to have a clear picture on it:

[![snapshot][1]][1]

As you can see ADCL has all rows checked and when I hit submit it will not show the message box as ADCP has an unchecked box in 2nd column.

Here is part of my code that only works for CURRENT row :

```
  if (e.ColumnIndex == this.dataGridLocationDetails.Columns["ColIssuePermission"].Index) {
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridLocationDetails.CurrentRow.Cells["ColIssuePermission"].Value) == false)
                    {
                        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Issue Permission is unchecked. Do you wish to continue? ", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                        {

                        }
                        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
}
```

**UPDATED:**

```
   for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridLocationDetails.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (((Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridLocationDetails.Rows[i].Cells["colViewPermission"].Value) == true)
                       && (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridLocationDetails.Rows[i].Cells["colIssuePermission"].Value) == false)
                     ))
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridLocationDetails.CurrentRow.Cells["ColIssuePermission"].Value) == false)
                        {
                            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("The following Location ID has view permission but not issue permission:(LIST OUT LOCATION HERE)    Do you wish to continue? ", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                            {

                            }
                            else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
                            {
                                return;
                            }

                        }


                    }
```

Comment: So what is the trouble? If you can do it for one, why can't you do it for all?

Comment: The trouble is when I checked on other rows with all columns checked and hit submit , the message box wouldn't show up.

Comment: Can you show the code for that? It's far easier to help you with the code you tried that didn't work.

Comment: Okay I edited it. I am just not sure if my logic is correct or not.

Comment: I'm not experienced with WPF components, but I think you'll need to loop through each row to check in the same way that you're checking for one row, and then use a boolean outside the loop to determine if the message box should be shown (assuming you want one box for the entire list).

Comment: There are many ways to handle this, right now we dont know what event you are using. If MVVM was used, this would be a piece of cake. You'll have to loop the rows when any of those checkboxs are checked/unchecked and keep track of the ones that dont meet the condition and then show the user.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it

Comment: @Codexer, Yes it's MVVM

Comment: Thats not MVVM, that whole block of code isnt close to MVVM, you have hardcoded column names, referencing view controls etc... thats not MVVM. Also you would be using commands and etc.

Comment: Okay I tried doing it differently this way (see updated) . Unfortunately still the same results

Comment: If you are using MVVM where is the ItemsSource of the datagrid bound to?  Why not just traverse those items in the view model?

Comment: wpf DataGrid doesn't have `CurrentRow` property and dataGridRow doesn't have `Cells` property. use correct tags. also format your code block properly, 20+ spaces on the left cause lines to be shifted to the right and hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find a detailed answer:
Created a sample application. Please find the code of MainWindow.xaml.cs here.
Constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        entities = new List<SampleEntity>()
        {
            new SampleEntity() { Id = 1, Description = "Test 1", IsViewPermission = true, IsIssuePermission = true, IsActive = true },
            new SampleEntity() { Id = 2, Description = "Test 2", IsViewPermission = true, IsIssuePermission = true, IsActive = true },
            new SampleEntity() { Id = 3, Description = "Test 3", IsViewPermission = true, IsIssuePermission = true, IsActive = true },
            new SampleEntity() { Id = 4, Description = "Test 4", IsViewPermission = true, IsIssuePermission = true, IsActive = true },
            new SampleEntity() { Id = 5, Description = "Test 5", IsViewPermission = true, IsIssuePermission = true, IsActive = true },
            new SampleEntity() { Id = 6, Description = "Test 6", IsViewPermission = true, IsIssuePermission = true, IsActive = true },
            new SampleEntity() { Id = 7, Description = "Test 7", IsViewPermission = true, IsIssuePermission = true, IsActive = true },
            new SampleEntity() { Id = 8, Description = "Test 8", IsViewPermission = true, IsIssuePermission = true, IsActive = true }
        };
        dgMainGrid.ItemsSource = entities;
        tempEntities = new List<SampleEntity>();
        entities.ForEach(item => 
        {
            SampleEntity newEntity = new SampleEntity()
            {
                Id = item.Id,
                Description = item.Description,
                IsViewPermission = item.IsViewPermission,
                IsIssuePermission = item.IsIssuePermission,
                IsActive = item.IsActive
            };
            tempEntities.Add(newEntity);
        });                
    }
```

As you can see, I have set the items source of the datagrid to entities.
Hence, I am creating a new list of tempEntities which will hold a copy of entities but it will not change. You can use ICloneable interface and implement the same in the Clone method.
The submit button click:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string editedIds = string.Empty;
        foreach(SampleEntity temp in tempEntities)
        {
            if(temp.IsViewPermission && temp.IsIssuePermission && temp.IsActive)
            {
                SampleEntity entity = entities.Single(item => item.Id == temp.Id);
                if (entity.IsIssuePermission == false)
                {
                    editedIds += entity.Id + ", ";
                }
            }
        }            
        string message = string.Format("Issue Permission(s): {0} have been unchecked. Do you wish to continue?", editedIds);
        MessageBoxResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(message, "WARNING", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
        }
        else if (dialogResult == MessageBoxResult.No)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

It simply checks whether the entities bound to the datagrid have changed by comparing them with the tempEntities which holds the original value. Id is my primary key, you use yours.
Please also update your tempEntities everytime you save the changes.

Adding xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_StackOverflow.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_StackOverflow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgMainGrid">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Location ID" Binding="{Binding Path=Id, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Location Descriptioon" Binding="{Binding Path=Description, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="View Permission" Binding="{Binding Path=IsViewPermission, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Issue Permission" Binding="{Binding Path=IsIssuePermission, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Active" Binding="{Binding Path=IsActive, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Submit" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: But how do I list out the location ID that has view permission checked and issue permission unchecked in the message box??

Comment: If the user has changed multiple items then which one do you want to list out? or all?

Comment: See my updated code. If there are 50 rows. Let's say I clicked row A , row B and row C . Row B and Row C has issue permission unchecked. When i hit submit, it should throw a message box ( which is working with above updated code) and also list out location B and location C have unchecked box

Comment: If you see the picture , I need to list the location ID of the rows that has issue permission unchecked . I am not sure how to add that feature.

Comment: Please check my edited Button_Click method. Instead of Id, you will concatenate your location ids.

Comment: I don't understand, in your button submit, does it behave like the one my program? For example, what is EditedIds? My variables are all already declared . I am just enhancing it

Comment: editedIds is a string which will hold your location ids which are used later in the string message to display the Location Ids of the rows who's issue permission was unchecked. Why is it so difficult? just try to understand the code, consider one entity as your one row? editedIds += entity.LOCATIONID (your location id)

Comment: Because you are using too many different variables. I only need to call my location ID in the message box and that should do the job?

Comment: Please do one thing, I have added the xaml file as well. Just create a new WPF project and paste the code in the MainWindow.xaml and the MainWindow.xaml.cs class and run the application, uncheck issue permission for few rows and then click on Submit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166512/discussion-between-raviraj-palvankar-and-lord-jesus).